# How to define a sitemap for an AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, seo, google-crawlers

Now that google can crawl AngularJS websites successfully what is the correct way to define url link locations within your sitemap i.e. using the url hash fragment or template url?

For example, if i have the following entry as part of my routing configuration:

```
   when('/mypage', {
      title: 'My Page',
      templateUrl: 'resources/partials/directory/mypage.html',
      controller: 'MyController';
    }
    })
```

Should the sitemap use the template URL:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://mysite/resources/partials/directory/mypage.html</loc>       
</url>
```

or the hash fragment:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://mysite/mypage</loc>       
</url>
```